# Problems while applying a function to each element's content of a directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, io, ipython-parallel

I am trying to obtain the content of several .pdf files from a directory in order to transform them to text with tika library, however I believe that I am not reading the .pdf file objects correctly. This is what I tried so far:

Input:

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf'))):
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        print(f)
        text = parser.from_file(f)
```

Output:

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='/Users/user/Downloads/pdf-files/a_pdf_file.pdf'>
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Which is the most efficient way of walking through the content of the files in python?.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Try removing the "b" flag.

Comment: thanks for the help @brianpck, I removed it and I still have the same exception `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode'`.

Answer (score 1):

The tika parser receives a path and opens the file itself:

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf'))):
    parsed = parser.from_file(filename)
    text = parsed['content']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.... Is there a more fast way to do this for large scale files?.